# Rails3: how to set default conditions to has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, finder-sql

I have boxes and balls. Balls are in boxes. Ball can be either red and green.

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :balls
end

class Ball < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
  scope :green, where(:color => "green")
end
```

I want to set has_many only with green balls. I know that finder_sql method exists, but i don't know how to set via scopes.

I want that following examples to be equivalent:

```
@orders = @box.balls
@orders = @box.balls.green
```

Answer (score 7):

You can always use:

```
has_many :balls, :conditions => { :color => "green" }
```

It works in Rails3, but I am not sure if this syntax won't be deprecated due to some ActiveRecord::Relation equivalent. In the official documentation relased with Rails3 this syntax is still available, so I guess this stays out like it was in 2.3.x branch.

Comment: note that you would probably want to call the association :green_balls for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

And in Rails 3, it's changed slightly:

```
class Item
  scope :red, where(:colour => 'red')
  scope :since, lambda {|time| where("created_at > ?", time) }
end

red_items = Item.red
available_red_items = red_items.where("quantity > ?", 0)
old_red_items = Item.red.since(10.days.ago)
```

[Credit and more information](http://m.onkey.org/2010/1/22/active-record-query-interface)

Comment: I want to set scope only for has_many assotiation. I want to @box.balls to returns all balls with green color. And I want to Ball.all return all balls green and red.

Comment: Indeed. So you'd have on the Ball model, "scope :red, where(:coulour=>'red')" ... then, @box.balls.red

Comment: :)
I want to avoid use scope by hand. I want to set default scope for has_many, is it possible?

Comment: You need to set scope in the /app/models/ball.rb ------- after that, you'll say "Ball.red" to find all red balls. You can say "@box.balls.red".... If you want to just call "@box.red_balls" then create a "red_balls" method on Box that balls @box.balls.red"

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I was just looking to do the same thing, and I came across this question while searching.  I never found a solution, but I came up with something that works well.

For your example, you can do this:

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :balls do
    def self.extended(base)
      base.where_values += Ball.green.where_values
    end
  end
end

class Ball < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
  scope :green, where(:color => "green")
end
```

I'm not aware of the implications of doing this, but after some initial testing, it appears to work without issue.  There are other values that can be set, like `eager_load_values`, `join_values`, `order_values`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
default_scope :color, :conditions => { :color => "green"}
```

Use this

Comment: default_scope acts on whole model. But I need option that acts oonly on has_many association. I want to @box.balls to returns all balls with green color. And I want to Ball.all return all balls green and red.

Comment: DO NOT use this. Every time I have used `default_scope` I have regretted it. Be aware that there are [lots of potential foot-guns](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2012/03/be-careful-using-default_scope-and-order.html) related to this misfeature.